# CurrentDirectory and Excel-DNA

Tags: c#, app-config, excel-dna, working-directory

I'm using Excel-DNA and debbuging a c# code that is used in Excel by attaching the process to VS17.

My issue is that i don't understand why while debugging, my project's current directory switches to C:\Users\userX\Documents:

```
string test = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(); // C:\Users\userX\Documents
```

which is a directory not used at all in all the classes in my project and poses an issue as i'm using an app.Config to read some static data (which hence won't be retrieved):

```
string staticData = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["data"];
```

I'm wondering how i could overcome this issue ?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: So are you saying the `ConfigurationManager` doesn't find your app config file? because of the Current Directory isn't your application directory?

Comment: Actually the problem is that my .config specifies some parent folder of the working directory: `<add key="deposit" value="..\..\StaticDataFiles\Conventions.json"/>` which won't be retrieved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's Excel setting the current directory.

You can retrieve the full path to your Excel-DNA add-in with a call to `ExcelDnaUtil.XllPath`.